# Can I use FileHelpers with Xamarin

Tags: filehelpers

I would like to use FileHelpers in a Visual Studio 2017 project that compiles code for Android, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. FileHelpers works fine with Xamarin.

Furthermore, you can use the FileHelpers library in a .NET standard 2.0 project which is the recommended way for Xamarin applications to share code across multiple projects - one assembly used by both Android and iOS    projects. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/).